# how to override a pytest fixture, but still be able to access it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

I have a conftest.py and a plugin, both defining the same fixture with different implementations:

### conftest.py

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture
def f():
    yield 1
```

### plugin

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture
def f():
    yield 2
```

when installing the plugin, the conftest still overrides the plugin, so a test file will only see the conftest fixture, i.e.

### test_.py

```
def test(f):
    assert f == 1 # True
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

1. If the plugin is not installed, continue
2. Else, from the conftest plugin, yield the value of the plugin's fixture

I managed to get half of the way:

### conftest.py

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture
def f(pytestconfig):
    if pytestconfig.pluginmanager.has_plugin(plugin_name):
        # now what? I have get_plugin and import_plugin, but I'm not able to get the fixture from there...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I see is to try and get the plugin fixture value. If the fixture lookup fails, then no plugin defined it and you can do your own thing. Example:

```
import pytest
from _pytest.fixtures import FixtureLookupError

@pytest.fixture
def f(request):
    try:  # try finding an already declared fixture with that name
        yield request.getfixturevalue('f')
    except FixtureLookupError:
        # fixture not found, we are the only fixture named 'f'
        yield 1
```

Comment: Cool, though I don't get it. Why `f` in `request.getfixturevalue('f')` will not be evaluated to the overriding `f`?

Comment: Because in that case you'd get an infinite recursion, and the fixture lookup tries to avoid that with all forces.